# Datatables is not refreshing the updated / Added new row

Tags: datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I was trying to follow the below example:

http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html

In the example I found that when we add / update a record - the page does not refresh and the values are added / updated.

For my project my side, I have modified the table declaration as per suitability. However when I edit / Delete / Add - I always have to refresh the page to re-load the modified data via Ajax call - without which it still displays the old values.

How is the same possible or rather which configurations allows a row to be added / edited / deleted and without refreshing the table / page both the datatable and the backend database are updated.

Comment: I've run into much the same issue. Everything I find points to the returned JSON not being in the proper format. I've been tweaking the returned JSON with the postSubmit event, but have not found the magic combination yet.